# Display view defined inside activity

Tags: android

I have an activity 'A' which is called from Main activity every second until timer ends.

A is called to draw pulses until timer ends

```
public class A extends Activity
{    
*some code*    

   public class NestedView extends View   
   {   
         public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
         {

              * draw pulses
         }         
    }    
}
```

I want to display the "pulses view" in main.xml which already has some buttons and scrollers, text boxes etc. How can I reserve a portion of screen for this pulses to be displayed. I cannot redo the xml file because the above pulses are dynamic and the image has a red line traversing across x axis for user defined time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have both "A" activity and Main activity visible at the same time.

Instead, create a new View and add it to the layout in main.xml.  See [2D graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) documentation for an example.  It sounds like the section titled Shape Drawable might meet your needs.

edit:
You can access the view from within your activity by calling `(MyView)findViewById(R.id.my_view)`  From there, you should be able to configure your view with shared preferences, etc.

Also, this [article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) on updating the ui on timer might be useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357769/unable-to-use-shared-preference-within-class-extends-view