# Unable to use shared preference within a class that extends View

Tags: android

I am getting an error , when I try to access the `shared preference` from within class that extends `View`.

The Error : "`The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type ViewforRed`" ,

where ViewforRed is my class

Here is the sample code

```
 public class ViewforRed extends View

 {

       public final String PREFS_NAME = "GRAPHICS";
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);


           public ViewforRed(Context context)
             {
                super(context);

             }

         public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
               {


                 Paint paint = new Paint();

                 float  p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9;

   }

   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences) is a method of a `Context` object. So you can try:

```
public class ViewforRed extends View

 {

       public final String PREFS_NAME = "GRAPHICS";
       SharedPreferences settings;


           public ViewforRed(Context context)
             {   
                settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                super(context);

             }
```

Comment: How can I call/start an View, like I call an activity this way

 Intent j = new Intent(mContext, Airplane.class);

  startActivity(j);
My activity is this for ex : 
 
ViewforRed extends View
{
 
}

Comment: "ViewforRed extends View" is not an activity, it's a view. I think if you want to add a view, you have to use addView() from an activity. Or instantiate the view from within an activity and you can call the activity with an intent.